# How much RAM can I add to my laptop? and how many slots?

Tags: laptop, memory, performance, motherboard

I have a Samsung Series 5 530U3C-A01 model. My system says I currently have 4GB RAM. I want to add more to make it faster, but can't figure out:

1. What's the max RAM it can run, and max speed
2. How many slots does it have - Only 1, or perhaps 2 (And then I can buy an additional cheaper 4GB rather than a replacement 8GB)

I found these links, not sure they absolutely apply to my specific model (As I have a different country code in the end):

[This one for example says:](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Samsung-Series-5-530U3C-A01DE-Ultrabook.77219.0.html)

- 4 GB on board RAM and 2 GB (DDR3) in slot.

What does on board mean?

It also said max is 12GB and speed is 1600 MHz.

[While this one says up to 8GB, and 1333 MHz.](http://www.yuspo.com/en/notebooks/560904-samsung-5-series-530u3ca03.html)

**EDIT:**

I ran the scan, [these are the results](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/scanview/598F591A31D926C3).
still can't figure everything out:

It doesn't say anything about speed.
It says Max memory is 12GB?
And shows graphic of one slot. does it mean I only have one slot and it is already occupied with 4GB?

I also contacted the manufacturer and was told:

Original memory : 4GB (on-board memory, irremovable )

Available number of RAM slot space: 1

Maximum Capacity of RAM slot: 8GB

RAM type: DDR3 (1333MHz/1600MHz)

So, what is the bottom line, how much RAM should I buy, and in what speed? should I buy "low-voltage"?

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Samsung-Series-5-530U3C-A01DE-Ultrabook.77219.0.html

See performance stuff it maybe can help you, also this app: http://uptobox.com/lq9keg05v4oy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop has 4Gb integrated memory (called 'on board' on notebookcheck and 'internal memory' on the other site), that means it's soldered on to the motherboard and can't be replaced.

On top of that you have one free slot which supports 1333MHz or 1600MHz SoDIMM up to 8GB. Something like a Kingston KVR16LS11/8  should work fine and will bring you up to 12GB RAM.

Most recent RAM chips are perfectly capable of running on 1.35V or 1.5V ( which is JDEC standard). For instance the KVR16LS11/8 I mentioned works fine with both voltages (see [here](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16LS11_8.pdf)). It's just a matter of what your memory controller supports and which setting you chose (or is automatically selected) in the BIOS/UEFI. Most likely the Crucial you found can also run on both voltages, Crucial calls this 'dual voltage' (see [here](http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Crucial-memory-for-PC-systems/1-35v-1-5v-Dual-Voltage-DDR3-memory/ta-p/71731)).

Comment: Thanks! Should I go for the Kingston KVR16LS11/8 which is 1.5V or the Corsair Low voltage which is 1.35V? I can't tell if my original memory runs on 1.35 already, otherwise 1.35v won't be supported.

Comment: You could try http://www.hwinfo.com/ and run it in normal mode (don't check any of the boxes to the left at startup). In the System Summary window you will find the 'Memory Modules'  on the right hand side with a column V that will show you the voltage. However for many motherboards there is no reading for the internal modules.

Comment: thanks, though looks like it can't read mine as the module is blank. what shall I buy then? considering the Low voltage Corsair is about 5$ cheaper. worst case it would work at 1.5?

Comment: Oh I misread your comment, I thought you were curious about what voltage the internal memory has. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Download and run the [Crucial Memory Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner).  It should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: I ran it, Please see my edit.